# Skip accessing an image pixel value within a for loop C#

Tags: c#, emgucv

- Is it possible to block accessing particular pixel in an image, once
  we satisfy a condition inside a nested for loop? I need to skip that
  pixel in the next iteration through the image.
- Provided nested for loop tests for 2 images. Once the absolute diff
  between pixel matches the if condition, i wants to block accessing
  that pixel in the next iteration.

  ```
  byte[,,] watermark_arr = watermark_img.Data;
  byte[,,] cover_arr = cover.Data;

  //iterate through watermark image
  for (int x = 0; x < watermark_img.Height; x++)
  {
      for (int y = 0; y < watermark_img.Width; y++)
      {
          //iterate through cover image
          for (int i = 0; i < cover.Height; i++)
          {
              for (int j = 0; j < cover.Width; j++)
              {
                  if ((Math.Abs(watermark_arr[x, y, 0] - cover_arr[i, j, 0]) <= threshold)  //[x,y,0] --> r
                      && (Math.Abs(watermark_arr[x, y, 1] - cover_arr[i, j, 1]) <= threshold)     //[x,y,1] --> g
                          && (Math.Abs(watermark_arr[x, y, 2] - cover_arr[i, j, 2]) <= threshold))     //[x,y,2] --> b
                  {
                      flag = true;
                      count_hit[cnt - 1]++;
                  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If there will only be a single `i` `j` pair you want to skip, just store the `i` `j` combination and check to see if the counters are equal to the `i` `j` the previous iteration found.

If you only want to skip a few pixels during the next iteration, you can store them in a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` and check against them each iteration. (Or a `List<CustomCoordinateStruct>` if you think it's worth it for clarity/speed.)

If this will be true for many pixels, you're probably best off storing another array of `bool`s containing whether or not that pixel should be skipped.

Comment: Thank you. , Yeah i wanna skip the pixel only related to inner most 2 loops (related to cover image). So u mean to add the restricted coordinates to a list<> ? Then each iteration loop needs to check that list? Isn't it time consuming ? If i meant wrong, please explain in a psudocode.

Comment: That's one way to do it. @Olivier is right that a `HashSet` is better if that's the range you're in. If you have only one value to skip, storing indices is better, and if you have a huge number of values to skip, storing in an array is better. It really depends.

Answer (score 1):

I would store the indexes of the pixel to block in a `HashSet<T>`:

```
var blocked = new HashSet<int>();

...

int key = x *  watermark_img.Width + y;
if (!blocked.Contains(key)) {
    if (condition satisfied) {
        blocked.Add(key);
        count_hit[cnt - 1]++;
    }
}
```

*I'm not sure which indexes (x, y) or (i, j) you want to block.*

Note that a HashSet has a constant access time, no matter how many items you store.

If you need to store all the 4 indexes then you can switch to `long` and calculate the key from those 4 indexes. The indexes can all be in the range of about 0..2<sup>16</sup> or about 0..65535.

Comment: Please check my comment(i posted as answer) . My output is corrupted by the above mentioned change. Actually the output is to select an appropriate image from the system given images. Previously it was ok. Now it selects the wrong image.Correct me if wrong !

Comment: Of course it will yield a different count, since the count is incremented less times. Try debugging a very small image (2 x2 or so) and you will see what happens.

Comment: after this alteration, it always selects the first image in the system as output. Not checking other images. Can u explain how it works"int key = x *  watermark_img.Width + y;" ?

Comment: `x * watermark_img.Width` shifts x to the left and makes place for `y` on the right side. Note that `x` is "shifted" by the max+1 of `y` in order to make place for `y`. You can compare it to creating a decimal number: 10*5 + 3 = 53, except that the base is watermark_img.Width. You could as well just shift like this: `int key = x << 16 + y` (this gives a different number as the 1st calculation). If uses the left 16 bit of a 32-bit number for x and the right 16 bit for y. Seems to be even easier than the first method.

Comment: I'm not sure what the output is supposed to be. You seem only to incement a counter. I don't see your code outputting any image. Btw: it always increments `count_hit` at the same index since `cnt` never changes. If you are processing other images, you must reset the HashSet in between: `blocked.Clear();` or `var blocked = new HashSet<int>();`

Answer (score 0):

@Olivier , I followed the way , the final output changes due to this change. Previously the output was correct. I donno whether i have done it wrong. Pls correct me if so.

```
 //iterate thhrough watermark image
                for (int x = 0; x < watermark_img.Height; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < watermark_img.Width; y++)
                    {
                        //iterate through cover image
                        for (int i = 0; i < cover.Height; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < cover.Width; j++)
                            {
                                int key = i *  cover.Width + j;
                                    if (!blocked.Contains(key)) 
                                    {

                                        if ((Math.Abs(watermark_arr[x, y, 0] - cover_arr[i, j, 0]) <= threshold)  //[x,y,0] --> r
                                            && (Math.Abs(watermark_arr[x, y, 1] - cover_arr[i, j, 1]) <= threshold)     //[x,y,1] --> g
                                                && (Math.Abs(watermark_arr[x, y, 2] - cover_arr[i, j, 2]) <= threshold))     //[x,y,2] --> b
                                        {
                                            flag = true;
                                            blocked.Add(key);
                                            count_hit[cnt - 1]++;
                                        }
```

Comment: This is not a suitable change i needed. so i could't edit this change in my question above. I just tried what @Olvier said